# ArcGIS layer to KML Python script gives TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Tags: arcpy, convert, kml, typeerror

I have some shapefiles to convert into KML file with a specific legend icon. So I tried to rearrange symbology and convert those shapefiles into .lyr files. After that, I put those files into a folder and used the following Python script.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "E:/Layers"

# Set Local Variables
composite = 'NO_COMPOSITE'
pixels = 2048
dpi = 96
clamped = 'CLAMPED_TO_GROUND'

# Use the ListFiles method to identify all lyr and lyrx files in workspace
layers = arcpy.ListFiles("*.lyr*") 

if len(layers) > 0:
    for layer in layers:        
        # Strips the '.lyr(x)' part of the name and appends '.kmz'
        outKML = os.path.join(os.path.splitext(layer), ".kmz")
        for scale in range(10000):
            # Execute LayerToKML
            arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(layer, outKML, scale, composite, 
                                        '', pixels, dpi, clamped)
else:
    arcpy.AddMessage('There are no layer files in {}'.format(arcpy.env.workspace))
```

Which is a built-in code from the pro.arcgis.com resource site. But unfortunately, the program is showing errors and does not produce any result.
Error showed `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it your intention to create 10,000 KMZ files? range(10000) will return a list with values ranging from 0 to 9999.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot. No, I want to create kml files on a 1:10000 scale. from the tool description, I understand that if I put a number it will recognize it as a scale.

Answer (score 2):

The `splitext` splits the path into the root and the extension (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext). So the return value is a tuple. You probably want to choose the root. Therefore, you need to change the line in  your code as follows

```
outKML = os.path.join(os.path.splitext(layer)[0], ".kmz")
```

Comment: Thank You, It seems working

Comment: Please accept my answer if it works now @Jobaied